# Shortcut for %>% in RStudio?

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

It's great in RStudio to have already a key short-cut for `<-`, which is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

Wouldn't it be also great to have also a short-cut for `%>%`, which is possibly the second most frequent key sequence (after `<-`) that R programmers type?

Or maybe  there is already one?

Comment: "which is the second most frequent key sequence (after "->") that R programmers type" This is definitely not true for *all* R programmers.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + m`

Comment: Also I just noticed you said `->`. Who uses `->` more than `<-`?!?

Comment: Page 2: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rstudio-IDE-cheatsheet.pdf. Also, I believe OP meant to say `<-`, because Alt + - is `<-`

Comment: The problem I always have with these shortcuts is that they take just as many keys as typing `%>%` directly.

Comment: @alistaire I mean I partially get your point and if you rely too much on the shortcuts then it can be super annoying when you use a different editor. But at least in this case you do actually save some keystrokes.

Comment: @Dason One, but since two are the same in `%>%`, it's the same number of keys. Plus I don't have to alter my typing position to type `%>%`, which I do to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: Check out the [RStuidio IDE cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rstudio-IDE-cheatsheet.pdf) where this and other shortcuts are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve this in rstudio you can create an addin and reference a custom shortcut to your addin. Here is the reference page which will guide you through the process: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/

Comment: You don't need to; it's already bound to `ctrl + shift + m`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Maybe a bit of an overkill then...

Comment: Phil - Yes!   - As simple as ctrt+shift+m.  - Please post it as answer, I'll check it as the answer I've been looking for .  Thanks to all those who provided constructive feedback